# Malloc in C++ constructor

Tags: c++, c, exception, constructor

I have to interface with some C code from C++ class constructor (Intel library)

```
  class A{
    A{
     x = ippiMalloc();
     if(x==NULL) ...
    }
  }
```

In the constructor malloc function (intel version) is used. If ippiMalloc function do not succeed what is the correct way to handle it. Throw exception?

Comment: Ippi (Integrated Performance Primitives)

Comment: Warning if you're new to this: if there's a third-party smart pointer available with the ownership semantics you want, perhaps `shared_ptr`, then use that in place of a raw pointer. Otherwise, A should be a class dedicated only to managing the allocation and freeing of `x`. This isn't just airy-fairy "separation of concerns is good practice": it is astonishingly awkward to write an exception-safe class which is responsible for managing more than one resource, and a bit fiddly even with just one...

Comment: ... so failing to separate concerns won't just lead to a suboptimal design, it will quite likely cause you to write broken code right now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, an exception would likely be the most appropriate way to handle the error here -- at least it would be the cleanest way. This is also what the "new" operator would do on failure.

If your app isn't exception aware than you have a problem. In which case a factory method on the class might make sense.

```
static A * create() { ... }
```

Here you can wrap this into a non-exception program, likely returning null if you can't create the object.

Comment: Then again, if your app isn't return-null aware, you just introduced problems instead of removing them.

Comment: If your app isn't exception aware it /must/ be checking return values. You really don't have another option: exceptions and/or return values.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, add parentheses to the constructor :)
And yes, I would vote for throwing an exception, because the alternatives are not very pleasant, like setting some bool in class like object_state_is_not valid or something.

Answer (score 1):

Joining the previous answers - and [here](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/exceptions.html#faq-17.8) is a good explanation about why exceptions is the best way of error handling in constructors. (C++ FAQ Lite)